# Question in Center of mass and toppling

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, equilibrium, statics

Let's say a table has a heavy circular top of radius $R$ and mass $M$. It has four legs of lengths $l$ fixed symmetrically on its circumference.
Figure is something like thi

[image: Table]

Now they are saying if i put a mass on it such that it is outside that square{dotted one} then the table has a tendency of toppling.
My question is-

DOES THAT MEAN THAT IF I PUT A MASS ON THAT SQUARE REGION THAN IT WILL NOT HAVE ANY TENDENCY OF TOPPLING?

To me I can feel intuitively that in real life also when we apply force like at the periphery or nearer to it than it can topple. But why is that true(if it is) or not then what is happening?
The actual question was find the maximum mass that we can  put $anywhere$ on the table without toppling it.

Comment: *Yes* to question about mass within square. The question is asking for the maximum mass which is placed on an edge so that there is no toppling.

Comment: You mean placing mass within that square will not cause it to topple?

Comment: Yes the question is asking for the maximum mass for it to still just not topple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square dotted region is supported by the symmetrical placement of the legs at each corner of the region which will keep the system in equilibrium if an object were placed there, since (if) the center-of-mass of this object remains in the dotted region.

For it to topple due to a torque, there must be a mass and a pivot point, and anywhere within the square region there are no valid pivot points.

The same is not true for outside the dotted region, since any two legs can work as a pivot point in the event of a mass being placed there.

Comment: Does a pivot point have to be fixed or it can move or be in motion ? I mean we can find torque about any point.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _in motion_?

Comment: I mean bodies rotate without having fixed points or pivoted like I can translate and rotate so there is some torque.

Comment: I am satisfied with your answer to move on just seeing the body it seems it is not in equilibrium completely like there is a mass over it it should create some torque. I am little bit confused can you just tell me how net torque is zero.